# include ('xyz.php') in php file doesn't work

Tags: php, html, include

I'm trying to include a php file inside another php file, but it is not working and I don't know why.

Moreover, I'm getting no erroes. `allow_url_include` is enabled in *php.ini* file.

I'm using XAMPP server.

Below here is part of my code:

**q.php**

```
<div class="article">

<? php
include ('a.php'); 
?>
</div>
```

where **a.php** simply has echo statement:

```
echo "hello";
```

I'm posting bigger section of my code now.

```
<div class="artical">
    <?php
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "techinsight";
        $server   = "127.0.0.1";

        $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
        $db_found  = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

        if ($db_found) 
        {
            $SQL    = "SELECT * from questions";
            $result = mysql_query($SQL);

            while($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $x = $db_field['Qid'];

                while($x==1 && $x==NULL)
                {
                    $SQL      = "SELECT * from questions";
                    $result   = mysql_query($SQL);
                    $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                    $x        = $db_field['Qid'];
                }
            }

            if($x==$x) 
            {
                for($x; $x>0; $x--)
                {
                    $SQL      = "SELECT * from questions WHERE Qid=$x";
                    $result   = mysql_query($SQL);
                    $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $str_que  = $db_field['question'];

                    echo "<div class='dabba'>
                    <div class='block_a'> <?php include('a.php'); ?>  //here it is.
                    </div> <br>
                    <div class='block_b'>
                    it is 2nd section. <br>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class='block_c'>
                    last one.<br>  </div>

                    </div>  <br><br>";      
                }
            }                                    
        }     
    ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try to remove the space from the opening PHP tag. Read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php about the syntax of the PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php //Before you had <? php <--
include "a.php";
?>
```

Make sure the files are in the same directory.

Comment: both are in the same directory.ok I removed that extra space, but still not working. Is there any problem with div tag,as i wrote that php script inside div tags.

Comment: How do you know its not working? <br> What is in a.php?

Comment: because i placed <?php include('a.php'); ?> at two different sections in the same program just for testing purpose. but only one of the is showing result i.e. it prints hello.

Comment: Lets go basic, is it saved as .php? Or .html? Needs to be .php this counts for both files

Comment: as i said earlier, both of them are saved as .php

Comment: yes, by localhost. Is there any other alternative .

Comment: Ive seen people opening it with chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `<?` and `php`
Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a couple of things...

#### 1. Place the included file in the correct folder

Make sure that when you use `include` you either provide the folder path correctly or place the file in the same folder as where you reference / call it from.

#### 2. It is `<?php` and not `<? php`

You have a space too much. Actually, if you use `<? php` I believe PHP will look for a function called `php` as `<?` may also be an opening tag (assuming short tags are activated in your `php.ini` file: `short_open_tag=On`).

#### Bonus: make sure error reporting is turned on while debugging

Another thing that I'd recommend you to do is to setup your `php.ini` file to report for all errors while debugging:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure your above code would have resulted in a notification on the missing function `php`.

#### And the real bonus (following your updated post) - what you did wrong

You have added the `include` inside `echo` - obviously it won't work. So replace this...

```
echo "<div class='dabba'>
                <div class='block_a'> <?php include('a.php'); ?> ...
```

...with this...

```
 echo "<div class='dabba'>
                <div class='block_a'>"; include('a.php'); echo "...
```

Comment: after all above correction,still not working. Is there something with div tag,as i wrote that script inside div tags.

Comment: `div` shouldn't be an issue, unless your `article` class is set to `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` or any other css directive would prevent it from appearing... you may want to try php code here: [http://3v4l.org/](http://3v4l.org/) or here: [http://codepad.org/](http://codepad.org/)

Comment: neither display:none nor visibility:hidden are creating problem in my case. I'm exhausted. i couldn't help myself now.

Comment: for better understanding,do i send more code of it?

Comment: I updated my answer: you're actually echoing the `include` statement, correct it and it should work (provided the rest of the code is fine)...